# Failed to connect Azure postgres using JDBC Connection String - Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, azure-postgresql

Spring Boot

- application-uat.yml

> ```
> spring:
>   datasource:
>     username: "${DATABASE_USER}"
>     password: "${DATABASE_PASS}"
>     platform: postgres
>     initialization-mode: always
> ```

- application.yml

```html
spring.profiles.active: uat
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://test-invoicing-db.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres?sslmode=require&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidat$
server:
```

Getting Exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:58) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:210) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.createSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        ... 162 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:46) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        ... 167 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        ... 168 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: test-invoicing-db.postgres.database.azure.com
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
        ... 182 common frames omitted
```

It was working perfectly before now it doesn't without any changes in the application. I have checked other Postgres posts and tried to remove and add **@hostname** but still getting the error.

I can connect to the database locally and also jdbc connection locally but the JDBC connection fails from server and the same happened to the application deployed in another environment.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened but I fixed the issue by restarting the server. Most of the time Azure Server seems like they need to restart. Though it seems weird getting that error. Wasted 2 days. Damn, why didn't I try it earlier?